# Samba: How to permit access to a shared folder only for QEMU-guests, but not for other users?

Tags: virtual-machine, samba, kvm, qemu, shared-folders

I am using `QEMU/KVM` for virtualization of various guest systems and `Samba` to provide an exchange folder (shared-folder) between the host-OS and the guest-OS.

Now I want to protect this `Samba`-provided shared folder against foreign access. It should be accessible only by `QEMU`-virtualized guests, but not for other third party people in the same network.

---

**My current configuration in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` looks like that:**

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
dns proxy = No
wins support = Yes
usershare allow guests = Yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
lanman auth = no
ntlm auth = no
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
load printers = no
disable spoolss = yes

[Shared]
comment = Shared Folder for QEMU
path = /home/myusername/Exchange
public = no
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
force user = myusername
```

---

**Now the central question is:**

Do you have any recommendations how I could implement such a security hardening feature?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your samba to the virtual interface between guest VM and host.
 Edit 
**smb.conf**
and add below lines

```
bind interfaces only = yes
interfaces = lo br0
```

Comment: Should I insert your lines in the `[global]`-section or in the `[shared]`-section? And do I need my huge configuration at all? Maybe it is already enough to only specify the name of the workgroup in `workgroup = WORKGROUP`, but no need to put the rest?

Comment: [global] section. I am not sure about workgroup, looks like you need nmbd to make it work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/23568/where-does-the-samba-workgroup-come-from-when-samba-is-not-running

Comment: Thanks a lot! Binding the share to specific interfaces is seriously a great option!